# How would you eloquently say "doing something for the umpteenth/nth/n-tieth time"?

Tags: expressions

I want to say that someone was doing (something) for the N-tieth time in a row, but in a way that emphasises both that this action is performed again, after a substantial amount of times (successfully, with no emotional tint for the outcome of the actions) and that no one, neither the "actor" nor the narrator is counting *precisely* which time this is.

More exactly I want to write something like:
"She was reloading the gun for the N-tieth time", but in a way that will show that she has fired and reloaded the gun so many times, it's well past the easily numerable ones, like "first", "third", etc. and, yet, she doesn't count them.

EDIT:
This is for a short story, therefore I need an **eloquent** equivalent. Something that rolls of the tongue smoothly and is light and easy to read, as well as naturally flowing. It also needs to be somewhat complex, to that end I thank the people who have proposed the "umpteenth" answers, however (no offense) that sounds rural, uncouth and brings down the reader from the context I wish to establish. I realise it might be a good idea to specify the context, however it would be impossible at this point, as it only resides in my head in a fractured idea-state.

I was hoping there was an English equivalent to what we have in my country, which roughly translates to:

> "She loaded the gun for the following time."
>   "She loaded the gun for the subsequential time."
>   It sounds bad, but I'm hoping I'm getting the point across.

Comment: It would certainly be more "natural" to refer to *doing it [for the **nth** time*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for+the+nth+time%22) (that's about 14,000 hits, but there are none at all for the ***ntieth*** version).

Comment: Has she hit anyone?

Comment: @ab2, Every. Single. One. :)

Comment: If you are really looking for a 'less incouth' version of *umpteenth*, this is Primarily Opinion-Based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one word will do what you want.  How about ***"She reloaded the gun fluidly and repeatedly"***

**Fluidly** means moving like a fluid, in a smooth, continuous manner.  Synonyms for **fluid**, from [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fluid)   are:

> flowing, easy, natural, smooth, elegant, graceful, fluent, effortless,
>   feline, sinuous

**repeatedly** is defined [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=repeatedly+meaning) as:

> over and over again; constantly

Another phrase the OP might use is:

***Yet once again, she reloaded the gun.***

To my surprise, the search for [yet once again](http://www.hymntime.com/tch/htm/y/e/t/yetonce.htm) found that it it is from a poem *From Lands Afar* written for the Salvation Army's International Congress in 1914. (Author, Albert Orsborn).

**Edit in Response to Comment by Dave_Thompson_085**

See Google Books [Yet once again](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Yet+once+again%22&tbm=bks) for quotes from Shakespeare, Milton, Wordsworth, Dickens, Southey, and many, many other writers.  Just one example (Wordsworth) from dozens, perhaps hundreds:

> Yet once again do I behold the forms Of these huge mountains, and yet
>   once again, Standing beneath these elms, I hear thy voice, Beloved
>   Derwent, that peculiar voice Heard in the stillness of the evening
>   air, Half-heard and half-created.

Comment: "She reloaded the gun once again", brilliant!

Comment: @mathgenius thanks for the green check!  Glad you liked it.

Comment: The spelling is 'repeatedly'; your *link* is correct but your text is wrong twice. 'Once again' and 'yet again' are idiomatic, but the combination 'yet once again' is not. 'Yet again' is slightly more emphatic, which this OP wants.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 the number of hits for [*yet once again*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Yet+once+again%22&tbm=bks) in Google Books seem to disagree with your affirmation

Comment: Repeatedly - could you use this i think it will work

Comment: "Fluidly" doesn't really have anything to do with the question. "Continuous" as it pertains to "fluidly" does not mean repeatedly.

Comment: @Kenneth K It means she smoothly and repeatedly reloaded the gun.  The OP wanted to project a picture of grace and elegance.   Anyway, the OP accepted yet once again which I agree is better, with its literary and militant allusions.

Comment: Loading a gun "fluidly" is pretty jarring and purple, IMO. The kind of adjective that would make me full stop and think about what it even means. Why not something that alludes to dexterity/speed, and not reloading a gun 'elegantly' ?

Comment: @ab2 Where do you see "grace and elegance" mentioned in the question? To be clear, I'm not saying that you couldn't use that adjective as you have used it. I'm only saying that its usage here doesn't answer the question asked. "Repeatedly" by itself does this.

Comment: @Kenneth K  The OP accepted my second option "yet once again", or, to be precise, OP accepted "once again".  See his comment directly under my answer.  As to my first option, "fluidly and repeatedly", if I were to revise it, I would revise it to "smoothly and repeatedly".  To do a physical action smoothly often results in greater efficiency -- which in this case  means more reloads in a given time. The OP said in his edit he didn't want uncouth: grace and elegance are opposites of uncouth.  But he has selected a phrase with a long literary history ("once again"); is it perhaps time to move on?

Comment: Jesus Christ! This question has **exploded** since yesterday, I appreciate the help, but WOW! :D Anyway, I must admit that this question is, indeed, largely opinion-based, however one could always argue for and against an answer being "objective" or "correct". In the end this answer is exactly a short and elegant way to say what I want, with no tint of emotion, which would make it an objectively correct answer.

Answer (score 24):

**umpteenth**, adjective, informal –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/umpteenth)

> Relatively large but unspecified in number: *umpteen reasons; umpteen guests.*

Doing something for the *umpteenth* time.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something more eloquent. Check the edit.

Comment: @mathgenius - People seem compelled to upvote this answer, I implore you to replace the word in your title with this one or with *nth* time to improve searchability and usefulness.

Comment: @Mazura  When being upvoted is inevitable, just sit back and enjoy it.  I decided to regard the criticisms of my first answer, which the OP did not choose (I gave him two options), and the entire Q&As as a sociology lesson.

Comment: Ask me how many times this has been upvoted today...

Comment: @Mazura  Tell me your secret!  You must be emitting electronic pheromones!  And it is so unfair to Ward, who also posted umpteenth.

Comment: @ab2 - Agreed, their's was three seconds after mine AND includes *umpteen*. The secret can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: You are right - I will change the phrasing of my question to make it more seach-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

"umpteen," meaning a large but unspecified number or "umpteenth," meaning the latest in a long series would work:

> "She reloaded the gun umpteen times."

or

> "She was reloading the gun for the umpteenth time."

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something more eloquent. Check the edit.

Comment: +1 in an effort to reduce by a tiny bit the irrationality of the votes on this Q.

Comment: @ab2 Thanks, but I know the "penalty" for being not-quite-the-fastest...

Answer (score 2):

She was reloading the gun *again*.

Is this usage in the character's head/internal dialogue? Simply 'again' would indicate that it is a repetitive action.

In business terminology (and math and statistics), there is the idea of *marginal units*, which means the next unit, as in marginal cost, marginal profit, etc. However it does not flow well with the context you have proposed.

Comment: Thank you, this was very close to what I was looking for, but mister and/or missus ab2 just hit the mark. :)

Answer (score 1):

Matilda hefted the handgun. After years of work she knew, simply by the weight and balance of the thing, how many bullets were left. Three. She’d need more. Of course.

She scanned the horizon as she reloaded. Casual, autonomic, an act of physical memory. As familiar and easy as brushing her hair. No effort needed. The satisfying sound of gunmetal clipping into place.

Click the magazine latch off. *Dust on the Old Road, about 5 miles south.*

Flick the cylinder open. Thumb it round. Shake out the spent cartridges. One movement. *A truck- dust's too thick for a sedan.*

Snick three bullets into the cylinder. Flick cylinder closed. Spin. One movement. *In a hurry. Big hurry.*

Matilda snuggled down behind the rocks. Shaded her eyes, watched as the dark shape of the vehicle formed out of the heat shimmer. Rehearsed the hit.

Comment: This answer would be better suited to writers.SE. At English.SE we talk *about* the language. For this question, a good answer would suggest a word, with a definition for it from a (hopefully reputable) source, and a link to that source. An example usage of the word may be included.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I did provide an answer to the needs of the original questioner, who asked for an eloquent way to express an idea.I assumed he wasn't looking for a replacement word or two. I gave an example (loosely based on Cormac McCarthy) of how a writer should suggest an idea through the setting, and the actions of his character, rather than simply describing what happens. Show, not tell.

Comment: If you could place in **bold** the one word or phrase which suggests most strongly someone loading  a gun in a repetitive mechanical way, as if in *auto pilot* the answer would then be quite good. You *have* answered the OP's request for something "elegant", but no doubt they are looking for a short phrase or expression not three or four short paragraphs. Oh, you can use the "auto-pilot" if you like, and if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using "[**over and over**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/over-and-over?q=over+and+over+) (again)" if you want to emphasize the repetition of the action for unspecific times. *Over and over* means:

> Again and again: '*doing the same thing over and over again*'

Your example:

> She was reloading the gun over and over.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits well into the context, but one option to consider might be to not talk about the many times she has reloaded, but instead let that be inferred by the reader, from the way she does it: **With practiced, exact movements, she reloaded the gun**.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! This is, indeed, a valid point, however I insist on keeping my approach this time. And I do not wish to offend you, but your answer seems more like an advice of changing the wording altogether, rather than giving and answer to my question. If I am correct, english.SE is about the English language and not the way of writing, in general.

Comment: @math: Thank you for your kind words. Good to hear you know what kind of solution you need! 
What motivated my response was in part that I thought this might be a case of the [XY problem](xyproblem.info): although this approach is interesting from the point of view of English vocabulary, perhaps the real, underlying problem could be tackled better in another way. (Now, of course, I know better.)
Moreover, reading the question again, I realize that the example sentence I gave is not a very good fit for what you described. My apologies for not reading your question more closely.

Answer (score 0):

[Time and again](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/time+and+again) she reloaded the gun.

> very often: '*Time and again I have had to remind my son to study before
>   going out with his friends.*'

[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms]

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. I have edited your post and please try to follow the format next time. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind introducing a tinge of tiresomeness in the repetition, *[Ad Nauseam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_nauseam)* is a fit for what you've described

> referring to something that has been done or repeated so often that it has become annoying or tiresome
>
> > *e.g.* She was reloading and firing the gun *Ad Nauseam*

Again, there's an element of unpleasantness here, indicating that she's performed the action to the point of irritation

Comment: Thank you, that is certainly an interesting point, however the exact nature of the adnauseam must be avoided in my case, since the persona is neither tired not annoyed by the action. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something which a subject has done many times, and will do many times again, is quite possibly *habitual*:

While we cannot say:

> She habitually loaded the gun.

because that refers to the habitual behavior as such, without making it clear that the action is going on now, we can express that with a more complicated construct:

> She performed her habitual gun loading.

(She loaded her gun now, as she has many times before and will do again.)

The "as usual" phrase expresses something similar, more succinctly:

> She loaded the gun, as usual.

We can also involve the word *ritual*, which refers to a sequence of repeated actions. If something is a ritual, it has been carried out many times before, and will likely be carried out many times again:

> She performed her gun reloading ritual.

Something that is more of a personal habit can be *characteristic*.

> He dismissed the visitor with his characteristic hand wave.

(He has a particular hand wave that he has used before and will do again.)